# How to append lines to a new file with AWK

Tags: awk, io-redirection

I am trying to append lines to some new files with awk in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
    FS = "[ \t|]"; }
{ 
    print $5 "\t" $13 "\t" $14 >> "./bed/" $5 ".bed";
}
END { 
}
```

New file is created with filename derived from a field of awk input file (5th field). I am unable to execute this script since it fails with

```
awk: ./blast2bed.awk:6: (FILENAME=blastout000 FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `./bed/AY517392.1.bed' (No such file or directory)
```

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory `bed` has to exist so create it first with `mkdir bed` either before you run your script or in the `BEGIN` block. You should also add brackets around the output file:

```
print $5"\t"$13"\t"$14 >> ("./bed/"$5".bed")
```

Notes: You don't need to end lines with `;` if you have a single statement per line and the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks are optional.

Comment: ... I am sorry... I created bed directory first; then I deselected it with selective sync in Dropbox, and it disappeared.. Thanks for your  quick answer though.. It was that.